# Android app can't install after switching from Apportable to Cocos2d-x

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, code-signing, apportable

Recently I have switched from using Apportable to Cocos2d-x but unfortunately when I try to update my app it says that

> App not installed

Also Google Play Game Services shows me warning that

> The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name
>   and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer
>   Console...

However my app is correctly signed with the release keystore and Client ID is correct. I have also checked if the certificate fingerprints of the latest released version match the ones that are in the newest version and they match.
The only difference is between file names in META-INF folder. The Apportable apk has CERT.RSA and CERT.SF files but the Cocos2d-x one has MYKEY.RSA and MYKEY.SF
Could you please enlighten me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have managed to fix this problem.
I've changed:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
```

to:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x20000" android:required="true" />
```

and now everything works correctly.